# Ember stripe's elements implementaion

Tags: javascript, ember.js, stripe-payments

I am totally new in front end and ember. I am trying to implement stripe's elements in to my ember application. I have been digging around internet with add on, however it dont seem like there is any stable ember add on for that.

So, I would need to back to the basic. Implement it from the stripe original lib.

The stripe given example, is using CDN to hook the JavaScript lib into the HTML.
However, to use the javacript in controller, we need to import it controller.
For example, 
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_ggwem1grAd10e0PJnt0eQy9S');

How can I use this on my controller, or component?
How they wrap this in to add on and make it to a services?

Please, point me to the right direction. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I’d start by looking at this addon’s setup of Stripe Checkout: https://github.com/smile-io/ember-cli-stripe/blob/master/addon/services/stripe.js

They’re loading the script tag lazily when the service is first initialized.

For now, you could probably copy the code out, but in the long run it would be great if you could send in your adjustments so the whole community can use Stripe Elements too